# Scrape table with BeautifulSoup--Python

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a table from this website:

https://covidactnow.org/state/CA

I am using the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://covidactnow.org/state/CA'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

soup.find_all('tr')
```

I believed the code should find the table however it returns an empty list.

Comment: The data rendered by java scripts.You need to use browser tool like selenium.Beautiful soup can't handle java scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@KunduK is right. You need to use selenium

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='Your:/Path/to/chromedriver.exe') 
driver.get("https://covidactnow.org/state/CA")
time.sleep(5)
html = driver.page_source
tables = pd.read_html(html)
data = tables[-1]
driver.quit()
```

Comment: hello dear Prakhar - many thanks for sharing your idea and for giving help. I want to learn and i am just diving into all these BS4 and selenium things. The question is - do i have to install the webdriver first - to run this examplecode here on my winmachine too!? Love to hear fom you - regards zero

Comment: hi @zero yes, you actually need to install selenium. To be specific 

pip install selenium should do the job. Next, you need to download chrome driver matching your chrome version and provide the exe path after downloading this to above driver path. Let me know if i am not clear